# doubt about ring homomorphism. in $f(a)=a^2$

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Consider the following statements

(a) If R is a commutative ring with unity and $f:R\to R$ be a ring homomorphism defined by $f(a)=a^2$ then $1+1=0$

(b) If R is a commutative ring with unity and $f:R\to R$ be a ring homomorphism defined by $f(a)=a^3$ then $1+1+1=0$

then which of the following is true..

If I consider the ring as $\mathbb{Z_2}$ for (a), with $f(a)=a^2$ then we can see

$$\begin{aligned}f(1+1)&=f(0)\\\ f(1)+f(1)&=0\\\ 1+1&=0\end{aligned}$$

Similarly I can use $\mathbb{Z_3}$ for option (b).

But the option must be valid for all the commutative ring so I am not getting what to do here.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is it a unital ringhomomorphism, do you require that 1 maps to 1?

Comment: For part (a), notice that $(a+b)^2=f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)=a^2+b^2$, and then consider the case where $a=b=1$. Once you've got that, part (b) is pretty similar.

Comment: For the second case this method gives $6=0$. It seems unclear how to get $3=0$ from this.

Comment: @Tom's comment answers the question for a). The mapping from b) is the identity on $\Bbb Z_6$, however.

Comment: Sorry @Amateur_Algebraist, you're right - I clearly wasn't very thorough with part (b). So the conclusion is statement (b) is false then, it appears, as $\text{Id}_{\mathbb{Z}_6}$ works?

Comment: Yes, or $\text{id}_{\Bbb Z_2}$ for that matter.